# Как обозначить имя файла при создании ярлыка Kubuntu?

Tags: linux, desktop, kde, kubuntu

Допустим у меня есть файл photo.jpg, программа program.py, и мне нужно создать ярлык на рабочем столе, для удобного перетаскивания photo.jpg на ярлык и чтобы в команде подставлялось имя файла, то есть примерно вот так: *перетаскиваю фото на ярлык*, выполняется команда program.py {имя файла}, из папки program.py. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: *вместо имени файла, полный путь к файлу который перетаскиваем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html полное описание.

Используй %U, %F, %u или %f в строке Exec. Большие буквы для списков, маленькие для одиночных. U - выдаст путь через file:///home/eri/file.jpg. F - через /home/eri/file.jpg

Посмотри ещё раздел действия (Actions) что добавить несколько действий над файлами через один ярлык.